# Magento not valid template file:adminhtml\base\default\template\login.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I have been debugging Magento Admin using PHP Storm these days and it's OK all the time. But today I came across this problem all of a sudden.

I have tried below but it didn't work.

- Restart PHP service
- Clean Magento cache
- Revert all my local changes (these changes are just for custom module, no system change included)
- Restart my PC

I also googled but no clue found. As far as I know, base directory is not involved in Magento admin login.

So any idea about it?

Comment: is the file login.phtml reside there actually?

Comment: No. IMO, Magento Admin should not look up login.phtml in "base" directly (adminhtml\ **base** \default\template\). Base directory is only existing in frontend.

Comment: check your file here first: adminhtml\default\default\template\login.phtml. check if it is not renamed

Comment: Magento will look into base directory after adminhtml if the file is not found. Try renaming any adminhtml template file and observe any error in exception.log file

Comment: I checked the commit history of directory adminhtml\default\default\template\ and found someone deleted login.phtml  ! Great hint, Dushyant! So many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me, was also as the last comment:

> I checked the commit history of directory
>   adminhtml\default\default\template\ and found someone deleted
>   login.phtml !

So i created a new login.phtml in adminhtml\default\default\template\ and then i copied content from the basic login.phtml file and it now works.